# intente hacer que desde mi ddbb se muestren imagenes en un treeview pero no para de salirme el mismo error (Error al cargar datos: Item 1 not found)

Tags: python, tkinter

pues este es el codigo la verdad ando aprendiendo asi que me seria de mucha ayuda si me pudieran responder esta cuestion, gracias de antemano

mas o menos para dar mas contexto a mi problema es que intente hacer que se muestren imagenes al lado de los datos dentro de las celdas de treeview pero cada vez que intento esto me sale un error que item 1 not found

llega a ingresar a la base de datos normalmente, obtiene el primer dato de la tabla pero ya no obtiene mas datos, imagino que es por el error en cuestion

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from conexion_mysql import conectar
import io
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class Ventana2:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.ventana2 = tk.Toplevel(self.root)
        self.ventana2.title("Ventana 2")
        self.ventana2.geometry("800x600")

        self.buscador = tk.Entry(self.ventana2, width=40)
        btn_agregar = tk.Button(self.ventana2, text="Agregar", command=self.agregar_dato)
        btn_editar = tk.Button(self.ventana2, text="Editar", command=self.editar_dato)
        btn_eliminar = tk.Button(self.ventana2, text="Eliminar", command=self.eliminar_dato)

        self.lista_datos = ttk.Treeview(self.ventana2, columns=("ID", "Tipo", "Fuente", "Imagen"), show="headings")
        self.lista_datos.heading("ID", text="ID")
        self.lista_datos.heading("Tipo", text="Tipo")
        self.lista_datos.heading("Fuente", text="Fuente")
        self.lista_datos.heading("Imagen", text="Imagen")
        self.lista_datos.column("ID", width=50)
        self.lista_datos.column("Tipo", width=100)
        self.lista_datos.column("Fuente", width=100)
        self.lista_datos.column("Imagen", width=100)

        self.imagenes_miniatura = []  # Lista para almacenar las miniaturas de las imágenes

        self.cargar_datos()

        self.buscador.pack(pady=10)
        btn_agregar.pack(pady=5)
        btn_editar.pack(pady=5)
        btn_eliminar.pack(pady=5)

        self.lista_datos.pack(pady=20)

        btn_volver = tk.Button(self.ventana2, text="Volver al Menú Principal", command=self.volver_al_menu_principal)
        btn_volver.pack(pady=10)

    def cargar_datos(self):
        conexion = conectar()

        if conexion:
            try:
                # Cargar datos de la tabla datos_covid utilizando Pandas
                consulta = "SELECT id, tipo, fuente, imagen FROM datos_covid"
                # Crear una conexión mediante SQLAlchemy
                engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:4568@localhost/Covid_19')
                df = pd.read_sql_query(consulta, engine)

                # Mostrar datos en la lista
                for index, fila in df.iterrows():
                    id_dato = fila['id']
                    tipo = fila['tipo']
                    fuente = fila['fuente']

                    # Convertir el BLOB a miniatura de imagen utilizando Pillow
                    imagen_blob = fila['imagen']
                    imagen_pil = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imagen_blob))
                    imagen_miniatura_pil = imagen_pil.resize((100, 100), Image.LANCZOS)
                    imagen_miniatura_tk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen_miniatura_pil)

                    # Insertar datos en la lista
                    self.lista_datos.insert("", "end", values=(id_dato, tipo, fuente, ""))

                    # Agregar miniatura de la imagen a la fila
                    self.lista_datos.set(id_dato, "Imagen", "")  # Añadir espacio para la miniatura de la imagen
                    self.lista_datos.set(id_dato, "Imagen", imagen_miniatura_tk)

                    self.imagenes_miniatura.append(imagen_miniatura_tk)

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error al cargar datos: {e}")
            finally:
                conexion.close()

    def agregar_dato(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("Mensaje", "Funcionalidad de agregar aún no implementada")

    def editar_dato(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("Mensaje", "Funcionalidad de editar aún no implementada")

    def eliminar_dato(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("Mensaje", "Funcionalidad de eliminar aún no implementada")

    def volver_al_menu_principal(self):
        self.ventana2.withdraw()
        self.root.update()
        self.root.deiconify()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Ventana2(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: as intentando: `self.lista_datos.insert(parent="", index="end",image=imagen_miniatura_tk,values=(id_dato, tipo, fuente,))`??

Comment: Tkinter no sabe tus intenciones de que la primera columna sea la id del item. Por lo tanto, asigna a cada item una id generada automaticamente. La solución es que, al insertar un dato, aclares explicitamente la id del item a insertar con el argumento iid, en este caso, siendo iid=id_dato